Magento2 module conflict issue Amasty Ajax add to cart not working when weltpixel GA4 enabled
Magento2 module conflict issue
I have Amasty Ajax add to cart but it is not working when weltpixel GA4 enabled, basically if I disable weltpixel GA4 then on list page when click Add to cart there comes a popup which asks for please select variant popup but same doesn't happen when I enable weltpixel GA4, in this case it directly redirects me to details page
Not sure how to solve this issue

have you checked console log?

Yes I did but not able to get any error

You need to check in the GA4 module where an observer or plugin was created for add to cart event so you just put log or debug the code by commenting out code line by line you may find the conflict code in it.
